# Is $C^{0}([a,b])$ dense in $C_{b}([a,b])$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm pretty certain the answer is no, but I haven't thought of any pathological counterexamples. I was inclined to think that the function on $[0,1]$ taking $1$ on the rationals and $0$ otherwise would work, but I think this can be uniformly approximated by step functions (if you fix an enumeration of the rationals beforehand).

Comment: With usual notations, you have $C^0([a,b]) = C_b([a,b])$, because both are just $C([a,b])$. What are the notations meant to denote in your question?

Comment: $C^{0}$ refers to the space of continuous functions and $C_{b}$ to the space of bounded functions (both over $[a,b]$.

Comment: Normally, $C_b$ denotes the bounded _continuous_ functions. Using $C$ for a space of (possibly) discontinuous functions is highly irritating. The bounded functions might be denoted by $B([a,b])$ if $B$ is not otherwise needed. Or $\ell^\infty([a,b])$. Anyway, which topology on the space of bounded functions?

Comment: The topology generated by the sup-norm is my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the involved norm is the supremum norm. In this case, $C^0([a,b])$ is a closed subset of $C_b([a,b])$ because continuity is preserved under uniform convergence. Since $C^0([a,b])$  is a proper subset of $C_b([a,b])$ (the characteristic function of $[a,(a+b)/2]$ belong to $C_b([a,b])$ but is not continuous).

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, doesn't this just show the space of continuous functions is a proper subset of the space of bounded functions? Is there a reason why we can't find a continuous function arbitrarily close to this characteristic function?

Comment: Arbitrarily closed with respect to which norm? That's the key point. It cannot be approximated for the uniform norm because there would be continuity at $(a+b)/2$.